# Sorting in Swift fails

Tags: swift, sorting, dictionary

I want to sort my Dictionary itemDictionary which I defined as:

```
var itemDictionary  = [String: [Items]]()
itemDictionary = itemDictionary.sorted { $0.0 < $1.0 }
```

But then I'm getting following error code:

> Cannot assign value of type '[(key: String, value: [Items])]' to type '[String : [Items]]'

Does anyone have an idea why this might be?

Comment: FYI - Dictionaries are unsorted collections. Why are you trying to sort a dictionary?

Comment: A dictionary is an unordered collection type by definition. The result of the `sort` function applied to a dictionary is an **array** of tuples. That's what the error message says: *You cannot assign a value of type array to type dictionary*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dictionary` is unordered by definition. You can only call `sorted` on it, because since Swift 4, `Dictionary` conforms to `Collection`,but due to the unordered nature of the `Dictionary` type, the return value of calling `sorted` on a `Dictionary` will be `Array<(key: Key,value: Value)>`, so an array of tuples, where the tuples contain the key-value pairs.

If you need a sorted data-structure, you should consider using a data structure that can actually be ordered.

Comment: Oh okay thanks for this information! Can you give me an Example ? I only need to save the key and the array of data..

Comment: You can easily create your own generic struct with properties for key and value and create an array of those objects if you really both need the key-value pairs and the ordering, but you'll lose the easy subscripting that `Dictionary` gives you. You'll need to make a compromise in any case if you want to keep both the ordering and the key-value pair functionality.